# Our company needs to perform automation testing for charts like pie chart, bar chart, which testing tool I should go with?

Tags: automated-testing, tools

My company designed dashboard for database data, I need to find best tool who will automate company's website
This dashboard contains all types of charts like pie chart, bar chart, line chart etc and I need to automate this chart to find whether all charts are working fine or not
How could I achieve this?

Comment: The technology your company is using based on javascript, flash, html5 or WPF, or Swing, or etc.? Automation is technology dependent in many cases.

Comment: Javascript and I guess using third party library for showing charts like D2Charts,HighCharts

Comment: Then you can use the tools which deal with DOM tree. Selenium, WebDriver, CodedUI, etc. I don't know all of them. I think you should do a few POCs to figure out which one is proper for your company and the cases you have to face.

Answer (score 2):

If what you care is the visual aspect of your charts, a tool like Selenium might not be enough. You should take a look to "visual tests" tools like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), [PDIFF](http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/), [PhantomCSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS), [Huxley](https://github.com/facebook/huxley). And maybe you could end up using both type of tools: Selenium to navigate in your app/site and visual-tool to check that the visual aspect of your graph is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Ranorex 5.0 it's a great took to work with pie charts and bar graphs. It is based on dot net framework hence uses c# language, I am saying this because I have worked on this tool and work with bar graphs and pie charts. There are various cases in which we have to validate the tool tip on a bar graph and with the help of this tool it worked seamlessly

Comment: Have you been able to use it to validate more than just the tool tip; for example the shapes, colours, sizes of the data displayed in the graph?

Comment: Well i have not tried it for shape but you can work with color and the size of data. With whole .net functionality at your finger tips the quality of scripts just depends upon your imagination and more over the tool support is just incredible and your queries are always herd with priority and the license cost is also minimal

Answer (score 0):

Selenium + [Ocular](https://github.com/vinsguru/ocular)

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.testautomationguru.ocular</groupId>
    <artifactId>ocular</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

You can compare specific WebElement

```
Ocular.snapshot()
      .from(this)
      .sample()
      .using(driver)
      .element(element)
      .compare();
```